# Python - Ending Time with 24 hour clock logic with leading zeros

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working on [this intro to python online course](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/#pybox8). I am close to a solution to this problem which reads:

> This program takes two lines of input. The first line is a "starting time" expressed in a 24-hour clock with leading zeroes, like 08:30 or 14:07. The second line is a duration D in minutes. Print out what time it will be D minutes after the starting time. For example, for input

```
12:30
47
```

Output:

```
13:17
```

Hints given:

```
Break the input into hours and minutes.
Final minutes should be (M + D) % 60.
Final hours requires //60 and % 24.
```

My solution so far:

```
ST = input()
STlen = len(ST)
D = int(input())

for position in range (0,STlen):
   if ST[position] == ':':
      H = int(ST[0:position])
      M = int(ST[position+1:STlen])

#minutes section
final_min = (M+D) % 60
if final_min < 10:
   finalminstr1 = str(final_min)
   zeroed_finalmin_str = '0' + finalminstr1
   final_min = zeroed_finalmin_str
else:
   final_min = (M+D) % 60

#hours section
if D > 60:
   finalhr = (D // 60) + H
elif (M+D) % 60 > 0 and H % 24 == H and D < 60:
   finalhr = H+1
if finalhr == 24:
   finalhr = '00'

#getting final end time ready
finalminstr = str(final_min)
finalhrstr = str(finalhr)
endtime = finalhrstr + ":" + finalminstr
print(endtime)
```

I think my approach is too convoluted and would waste processing time. It's also breaking when I use

```
15:33
508
```

as input data. The correct output should be 00:01, but I'm getting 23:01.

Any ideas on how to improve my code? **Also, please do not use functions or methods.** We haven't learned how to use functions or methods yet!

Comment: Note that when `D > 60`, such as your example broken case, you never check if `M + D > 60` , so you are left with your incorrect answer of `23:01`.

Comment: Jordan, can you clarify? What do I do after checking whether or not M + D > 60?

Comment: Hi @StacyM, I added clarification and a different way of executing that block in an answer (Too long for a comment) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when D > 60, such as your example broken case, you never check if `M + (D % 60) > 60`, so you are left with your incorrect answer of 23:01.

I suppose what you actually have to check is if `M + (D % 60) > 60`, this means that you have to increase `H` by one, and then check if that pushes it over 24.  An easy way of doing that is just altering your `if` structure, I am not used to python, but it looks like `elif` means `else if` correct? if so, you could restructure that block to look like this:

```
finalhr = (D // 60) + H + ((M + (D % 60)) // 60)
finalhr = finalhr % 24
```

So if `D < 60`, then `(D // 60)` will be zero, and if `(M + (D % 60)) < 60`, then `((M + (D % 60)) // 60)` will also be zero.  The second line will make `finalhr` zero if it was equal to 24, and 1 if it was equal to 25, and so on. This should give you the correct number of hours.

Answer (score 4):

```
H,M = map(int,"15:33".split(":"))
D = int("50")
M_new = M + D
H_new = H + (M_new // 60)
M_new = M_new % 60
EXTRA_DAYS = H_new // 24
H_new = H_new % 24 # in case you go over 24
print "%02d:%02d%s"%(H_new,M_new,"" if not EXTRA_DAYS else " +%dD"%EXTRA_DAYS)
```

although really this is a case for datetime (heres how you would do it in the realworld)

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("13:55","%H:%M")
time_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=50)
print (my_date + time_delta).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
H, M = map(int, ST.split(":"))
m = (M + int(D)) % 60
h = (H + (M + int(D)) // 60) % 24
print "%i:%i"%(h, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. It includes the extra zeros in front of single digits that it looks like others didn't include. However, I'm also a beginner so it's probably longer/more complicated than needed...but it works. :)

```
time = input()
dur = int(input())
x=time.find(':')
hours = int(time[0:x]) 
minutes = int(time[x+1:len(time)])
newmin = minutes+dur

if (newmin > 59):
   plushrs = int(newmin//60) 
   newmin = newmin % 60
   hours = hours+plushrs
if (hours >23):
   while hours > 23: #incase they add more than a whole day
     hours = hours - 24
   if (hours <10): #adding the zero for single digit hours
     hours = '0' + str(hours)
else:
   hours = str(hours)
if newmin > 9:
   newmin = str(newmin)
   print (hours + ':' + newmin) #print out for double digit mins
else:
   newmin = str(newmin)
   print (hours + ':0' + newmin) #print out for single digit mins
```

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it this way - which was marked as correct. I guess there are more elegant ways but it is the way I think of it :-)

```
Lesson 8.5 - Ending Time

t = input()
p = input()
pos = 0

for myString in range(0, (len(t))):
    # print(S[myString])
    if t[myString] == ":":
        pos = myString
        # print(pos)
hh = t[0:pos]
mm = t[pos+1:len(t)]

hh = int(hh)
mm = int(mm)
p = int(p)
if (mm + p) > 59:
    hh = hh + (mm + p) // 60
    if (hh > 23):
        hh = hh - 24
    mm = (mm + p) %  60
else:
    mm = mm + p
print('{num:02d}'.format(num=hh) + ":" + '{num:02d}'.format(num=mm))
```

Cheers.kg

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
# Input time expressed as 24-clock with leading zeroes

# Starting time
Stime = input("Input starting time in format like 12:15. ")

# Duration in minutes
Duration = int(input("Input duration in minutes. "))

# Extracting integer numbers of 'hours' and 'minutes'
hour = int(Stime[0:2])
minute = int(Stime[3:5])

# Getting new 'hours' and 'minutes'
NewHour = ((hour + ((minute + Duration) // 60)) % 24)
NewMinute = (minute + Duration) % 60
if NewHour < 10:
NewHour = '0' + str(NewHour)
else:
    NewHour = str(NewHour)
if NewMinute < 10:
    NewMinute = '0' + str(NewMinute)
else:
    NewMinute = str(NewMinute)

# Print new time
print("New time is " + NewHour + ":" + NewMinute)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#receive user input
time=input()
dur=int(input())

#separate hours and minutes
hrs=time[0:time.find(':')]
mins=time[time.find(':')+1:len(time)]

#take care of minute calculation
newmins=(int(mins)+dur)%60

#take care of hour calculation
hrstoadd=(int(mins)+dur)//60
newhr=(int(hrs)+hrstoadd)%24

#add zeros to hour and min if between 0-9
if newhr < 10:
   newhr='0'+str(newhr)
if newmins < 10:
   newmins='0'+str(newmins)

#print new time
print(str(newhr)+':'+str(newmins))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is my answer:
I have split the time in 2 parts one for hours and one for minutes and then calculate them separately:

```
hour = input() #input from the user
minute = int(input())
#split the time string in hours and minutes
for position in range(0, len(hour)):
   if hour[position] == ":":
      h = int(hour[0:position])
      min = int(hour[position+1:len(hour)])
#below I have split the final answer in 2 parts for easier calculation
x = (min + minute)//60 #the number of hours 
y = (min + minute) - (x *60) # the final number of minutes
h1 = (h + ((min+minute)//60))%24 # the final number of hours that will be printed
p1s = h1//10 # we are calculating the first digit of the hour part
p2s = h1%10 # we are calculating the second digit of the hour part
p1d = y // 10 # we are calculating the first digit of the minutes part
p2d = y % 10 10 # we are calculating the second digit of the minutes part
s = str(p1s)+str(p2s) # we are converting them to strings (right part and the left obe)
d = str(p1d)+str(p2d)
if s == "24": # if the hour part is 24 we assign the correct value
   s = "00"
f = s+":"+d # a final concatenate
print(f) # and here we are
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
#My VARIANT
HM = input()
D = int(input())
h=int(HM[0:2])
MM=int(HM[3:5])
m = (MM+D)%60
hh = (MM+D)//60
h=(h+hh)%24
if len(str(m))==1:
   m='0'+str(m)
if len(str(h))==1:
   h='0'+str(h)
print(str(h) + ':' + str(m))
```